# How to use property triggers with dependency properties on a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I use property triggers in conjunction with dependency properties on a user control to set style attributes on a UI element by name?

I have a custom user control, `MyUserControl.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="NameField" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="NameBox" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="NameBox" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="NameField" />
        </Trigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NameField" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NameBox" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind, `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class MyUserControl
    {
        public bool IsEditable
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditableProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsEditableProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditableProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditable", typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public UserDetailedUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I include it in my main window like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <local:MyUserControl />
</Window>
```

My intention is to be able to include it like this:

```
    <local:MyUserControl IsEditable="True" />
```

And get the `TextBox` instead of the `TextBlock`.

When I compile, I get an error in the XAML:

> 'IsEditable' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.  (MyUserControl.xaml line 9)

I believe I need to do something to my `Value` attributes to set them to a literal boolean `true` or `false`, rather than the strings "True" and "False", but I'm not sure how to do that.

**Edits**

Andy suggests in the comments:

> Something like Property="local:MyUserControl.IsEditable" where local is an xmlns for MyProject

When I do that, I get a different error on the same line, "Unkown build error: Key cannot be null".

I think this is on the right track but the syntax isn't quite right... it seems wrong to be putting namespaces inside the XAML parameter value without using curly braces.

Comment: Don't you just need to reference the xmlns and type? Something like Property="local:MyUserControl.IsEditable" where local is an xmlns for MyProject

Comment: @Andy thank you for the suggestion -- i gave it a shot, see my edit. i think the idea is right but the syntax is off and i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use DataTriggers instead of the standard triggers so you can set the binding explicitly to the IsEditable property of the code-behind within the trigger.

Comment: isn't this more or less the textbook example use-case for plain-old property triggers, though? if they can't be used here, i struggle to see any scenario where one would use property triggers, aside from the triggers that are available out of the box, like `IsMouseOver`.

Comment: I think you have to use bindings for the property if you want to have control of it from the c# side.  As I currently understand it, plain old property triggers are best suited for interacting with other elements within the xaml.